# How to add a unit to a command argument?

Tags: boxes, unit-of-measure

Currently I set up a box of given length `#1` and width `#2` like this:

```
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
   This is a box of #1 by #2 centimeters:
   \framebox{\hbox to #1cm {\vbox to #2cm}}
}

% Usage:
\mybox{5}{8]
```

However this causes an error as it's not allowed to append `cm` to the parameters `#1` and `#2`.

Is there a way to append a unit to a command argument? Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass the unit as an argument because I also use the parameters in their original raw form.

Comment: You shouldn't need `\hbox` and `\vbox` here. The optional arguments to the LaTeX `\parbox` command are designed to specify the required height and width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no content for your second box, and are missing the required brace group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{%
   This is a box of #1 by #2 centimeters:
   \framebox{\hbox to #1cm {\vbox to #2cm{}}}%
}
\begin{document}
% Usage:
\mybox{5}{8}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way of doing it, plus an alternative that doesn't use `\hbox` or `\vbox`, but zero-width rules rather:

[image: Boxes of specific width/height in cm]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{%
   This is a box of~#1 by~#2 centimeters:
   \framebox{\hbox to \dimexpr#1 cm\relax {\vbox to \dimexpr#2 cm\relax{}}}%
}
\newcommand{\myboxx}[2]{%
  This is a box of~#1 by~#2 centimeters:
  \fbox{\rule{\dimexpr#1cm\relax}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#2cm\relax}}%
}
\begin{document}
\mybox{5}{8} \par
\myboxx{2}{2}
\end{document}
```

The key to modifying your argument from number to dimension is to use `\dimexpr`. Also, similar to using `\hbox to .. {...}`, you need to enclose the `\vbox to .. {...}` with braces as well.

Answer (score 5):

A cheap way to add a default unit of measure to an argument is to say

```
\sbox0{\dimen0=#1cm}
```

(instead of `cm` one can use any legal unit of measure). If `#1` is a number without a unit attached, the assignment will leave nothing to typeset in the box, which will have zero width. Otherwise `cm` will be typeset.

So here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\testforunit[2]{%
  \sbox0{\dimen#1=#2cm}%
  \ifdim\wd0=0pt
    \dimen#1=#2cm
  \else
    \dimen#1=#2\relax
  \fi}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{%
  This is a box of #1 by #2 (default unit centimeters):\hfill
  \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \testforunit{0}{#1}\testforunit{2}{#2}%
  \framebox[\dimen0]{\rule{0pt}{\dimen2}}%
  \endgroup\par}

\begin{document}
\mybox{2}{3}

\mybox{2cm}{3cm}

\mybox{1in}{2in}
\end{document}
```

With `\testforunit` we perform the test on `#2` adding `cm` if necessary and store the requested length in `\dimen#1`. The construction of the box is done with those two length but in a group where `\fboxsep` is set to `\fboxrule`, so that the frame will have the exact requested dimensions. In the example the first and second boxes are identical.

As suggested by Joseph, here is the "official" LaTeX kernel way of defining `\testforunit`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testforunit}[2]{\@defaultunits\dimen#1=#2cm\relax\@nnil}
\makeatother
```

---

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\@defaultunits` be as good an approach here (via a `\dimen`)?

Comment: What about a `\dim_set_withdefaultunit:Nnn \l_my_dim { #1 } { cm }`? You'll need it, eventually.

Comment: I'm not sure we will, actually :-) We have some need for this in implementing the NFSS in expl3, but there it's clear that the default unit is fixed (as `pt`).